# Access to SysWOW64

Tags: windows-10, permissions, copy-paste

I wanted to add a file to SysWOW64 in Windows 10 and I need permissions to copy files. I tried messing with permissions but I can't change anything. I need help quick.

Comment: Start a command prompt with admistrative rights. Then you don't need additional permission.

Comment: "I tried messing with permissions" - What did you do exactly.  Provide a screenshot of the properties of the folder your trying to modify the permission on.  You really should NOT be changing the properties of a system folder like SysWOW64, by default an Administrator user, has enough permissions to copy a file to that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `Super (Windows) + x`, click on `Command Prompt (Admin)`, then

```
cd ..
cd SysWOW64
copy %userprofile%\Desktop\test.txt .\
```

You're done!

*EDIT*: Obivously replace the first argument of copy (`%userprofile%\Desktop\test.txt` by the location of your file).

Comment: Nice answer, I'm missing only "As the @harper already says in his comment ..." :)